# Unable to access momentjs from 'meteor shell'

Tags: meteor

I have momentjs:moment added in my list of packages, I checked with `meteor list`, but whenever I launch `meteor shell` I'm unable to call `moment()`, it tells me `moment` is `'undefined'`.

It seems as though my app is able to execute code containing calls to `moment()`, shouldn't I also be able to do the same from `meteor shell`?

Comment: Try these two things: 1) Enter the shell once again and type >moment  Check if this printing anything?  2) Use meteor shell when the server is running, meaning, start your app and then let it load, open another console and type meteor shell once again. Tell me if this helps?

Comment: I updated meteor to the newest version, and all seems to be working now. Not sure exactly what caused the problem, but it seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem I was having by updating my version of meteor to 1.1.0.1. I don't know what was causing the error previously, but updating took care of the problem.

Comment: The problem started happening again, I'm not sure why, but rebooting my machine fixed the problem... for now...